# SQL Server creating two tables and comparing them

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 3 columns (in SQL Server 2012). One of the columns is a date column. What I would like to do is split the table for two specified dates and merge them into one table with an extra field. Hopefully the example below will explain.

Example of what I currently have.

```
Company   date         no_employees
ABC       2014-05-30   35
DEF       2014-05-30   322
GHI       2014-05-30   65
JKL       2014-05-30   8
MNO       2014-05-30   30
ABC       2014-01-01   33
DEF       2014-01-01   301
GHI       2014-01-01   70
MNO       2014-01-01   30
```

What I would like a query to return for me (not sure if its possible),

```
Company   start date no_employees   end date no_employees  diff
ABC       33                        35                       2
DEF       301                       322                      21
GHI       70                        65                       -5
JKL       0                         8                        8
MNO       30                        30                       0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @lowdate date = '2014-01-01'
declare @highdate date = '2014-05-30'

;with x as
(
  select company, min(no_employees) no_employees
  from @t records 
  where recorddate =  @lowdate
  group by company
), y as
(
  select company, max(no_employees)  no_employees
  from @t records 
  where recorddate = @highdate
  group by company
)
select coalesce(x.company, y.company) company, 
coalesce(x.no_employees, 0) start_no_employees, 
coalesce(y.no_employees, 0) end_no_employees, 
coalesce(y.no_employees, 0) - coalesce(x.no_employees, 0) diff
from 
x full outer join y
on
x.company = y.company
```

Answer (score 1):

[`PIVOT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (and [`COALESCE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) to generate the 0s) seems to do it:

```
declare @t table (Company char(3),[date] date,no_employees int)
insert into @t(Company,[date],no_employees) values
('ABC','2014-05-30',35  ),
('DEF','2014-05-30',322 ),
('GHI','2014-05-30',65  ),
('JKL','2014-05-30',8   ),
('MNO','2014-05-30',30  ),
('ABC','2014-01-01',33  ),
('DEF','2014-01-01',301 ),
('GHI','2014-01-01',70  ),
('MNO','2014-01-01',30  )

select Company,
       COALESCE(start,0) as start,
       COALESCE([end],0) as [end],
       COALESCE([end],0)-COALESCE(start,0) as diff
from
    (select
        Company,
        CASE WHEN [date]='20140530' THEN 'end'
            ELSE 'start' END as period,
        no_employees
    from @t
    where [date] in ('20140101','20140530')
    ) t
    pivot (MAX(no_employees) for period in ([start],[end])) u
```

Result:

```
Company start       end         diff
------- ----------- ----------- -----------
ABC     33          35          2
DEF     301         322         21
GHI     70          65          -5
JKL     0           8           8
MNO     30          30          0
```

This could easily be parameterized for the specific start and end dates to use.

Also, at the moment I'm using `MAX` because we have to have an aggregate in `PIVOT`, even though here the sample data contains a maximum of one row. If there's a possibility of multiple rows existing for the start or end date, we'd need to know how you want that handled.

Comment: there will only ever be maximum of one company per date so believe MAX should be fine. Just about to try it.

Comment: +1 seems like most of the other suggestions has one thing in common. They are missing full join. Pivot does not suffer under that limitation.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Table #temp(Company varchar(10), CDate date,emp int)      

Select T1.Company,T1.emp,T2.emp,(T1.emp-T2.emp) Diff
from #temp T1
    inner join #temp T2 On T1.Company=T2.Company and T1.CDate<T2.CDate
Order by T1.Company,T1.CDate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (Company char(3),[date] date,no_employees int)
insert into @t(Company,[date],no_employees) values
('ABC','2014-05-30',35  ),
('DEF','2014-05-30',322 ),
('GHI','2014-05-30',65  ),
('JKL','2014-05-30',8   ),
('MNO','2014-05-30',30  ),
('ABC','2014-01-01',33  ),
('DEF','2014-01-01',301 ),
('GHI','2014-01-01',70  ),
('MNO','2014-01-01',30  )

select Company,MIN(no_employees),MAX(no_employees),CASE WHEN MIN(no_employees) = MAX(no_employees) then  MAX(no_employees) else
MIN(no_employees) - MAX(no_employees) end as cNT  from @t
GROUP BY Company
```

Comment: just using `MIN` and `MAX` cannot be correct since the `GHI` row has the values `70,65` appearing in those two columns. Also, your `cNT` column looks like it would struggle to generate any non-negative value that isn't equal to the maximum. There's only two rows where it can generate the desired result shown.

Answer (score 0):

select the companies. Outer join the start date records. Outer join the end date records. Use coalesce to show 0 instead of null.

```
select 
  company, 
  coalesce(rec20140101.no_employees, 0) as empno_start,
  coalesce(rec20140530.no_employees, 0) as empno_end
from 
(
  select distinct company
  from records
) companies -- or use a company table if you have one
left join
(
  select company, no_employees 
  from records 
  where recorddate = '2014-01-01'
) rec20140101
  on rec20140101.company = companies.companyrec
left join
(
  select company, no_employees 
  from records 
  where recorddate = '2014-05-30'
) rec20140530
  on rec20140530.company = companies.company);
```

EDIT: And here is a way to scan the table just once. It's even a little shorter ;-)

```
select
  company,
  coalesce(min( case when recorddate = '2014-05-30' then no_employees end ), 0) as empno_start,
  coalesce(min( case when recorddate = '2014-01-01' then no_employees end ), 0) as empno_end
from records
group by company;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
;with cte as
(select 
 COALESCE(src.company, tgt.company) company 
 isnull(tgt.no_employees,0) 'start date no_employees', 
 isnull(src.no_employees , 0) 'end date no_employees'
 from
 tbl src 
 full outer join tbl tgt on src.company = tgt.company and src.date <> tgt.date
 where (src.date = (select max(date) from tbl) or src.date is null)
 and (tgt.date = (select min(date) from tbl) or tgt.date is null)
)
select *, [end date no_employees] - [start date no_employees] diff
from cte
```